# Bluetooth and headset Not working in ubuntu

Tags: bluetooth, headset

I have Ubuntu on my dell N4010 and until the day before yesterday it was working fine, but all of sudden my bluetooth doesn't show up and on system setting there mentions no bluetooth adapter was found

Could you help me out to solve this? My headset is also not working.
[image]
[image]

Results:

```
abindrardangol@AbindraRDangol:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Inspiron M5010 / XPS 8300 [1028:0010]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl

abindrardangol@AbindraRDangol:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1d57:5a66 Xenta 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:6480 Microdia Sonix 1.3 MP Laptop Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

abindrardangol@AbindraRDangol:~$ dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
[    0.256940] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.260726] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness
[    1.308256] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness
```

Comment: @smit please don't add the version tag unless the problem is somehow *specific* to this version and this version only.

Comment: @terdon♦ . i have the same problem in ubuntu mate16.10 but then i switch to ubuntu mate 16.04 and sound output is fine.after all as  you say i will not.

Comment: what does aditional  drivers say? screenshot of "sound" app please?

Comment: @tatsu i have uploaded screenshot of sound and bluetooth app and in aditional driver there is wireless driver of broadcomm and next one is mentioned unknown.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`  Thanks

Comment: @Jeremy31 included the results.

Comment: It seems that the bluetooth device is gone, see if BIOS has some setting in it

Answer (score 0):

I think your sound problems does not depending with your bluetooth issue.
You can get rid of most sound problems by using `alsamixer` via terminal, which is almost self-explanatory.

Comment: i could not understand figure out this one

Comment: @AbindraRajDangol What do you not understand? You don't have alsamixer? Or you have not typed in terminal the command `alsamixer` yet? Or do you think sound and bluetooth problem's have the same issue?